# Custom cursor image with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to change my mouse cursor to a custom image.

If possible I would like to do it on a spritesheet.
I can't do it from the css because I'm using it in a game. I already know how to decide when etc.

What I need to know is how do I change the cursor to an image, and deciding the image position and size?
Is there any easy solution similar to the drawImage's image position?

Comment: you **can** do it using css if you use javascript to modify the css...

Comment: I know I can do it in css, but if possible I rather dont, as I said in the post.

Comment: Setting the CSS for the cursor is the only way to hide it. Why would you not want to use CSS anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the CSS using javascript to hide the cursor:

```
your_canvas.style.cursor = "none"
```

You can then get the cursor's position (it's now hidden) with something like this:

```
your_canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (ev) {
    var mouseX = ev.pageX - GetTopLeft(your_canvas).Left;
    var mouseY = ev.pageX - GetTopLeft(your_canvas).Top;
});
```

Then you can modify your canvas to show your fancier cursor sprite at that location.

GetTopLeft is defined as follows:

```
function GetTopLeft(elm){

    var x, y = 0;

    //set x to elm’s offsetLeft
    x = elm.offsetLeft;

    //set y to elm’s offsetTop
    y = elm.offsetTop;

    //set elm to its offsetParent
    elm = elm.offsetParent;

    //use while loop to check if elm is null
    // if not then add current elm’s offsetLeft to x
    //offsetTop to y and set elm to its offsetParent

    while(elm != null)
    {

    x = parseInt(x) + parseInt(elm.offsetLeft);
    y = parseInt(y) + parseInt(elm.offsetTop);
    elm = elm.offsetParent;
    }

    //here is interesting thing
    //it return Object with two properties
    //Top and Left

    return {Top:y, Left: x};

}
```

Though I can't remember where I copied the GetTopLeft function from...

Comment: Yeah I have a function for mouse position on canvas allready, and just drawing the image as is as you and Mike Depies said was a very elegant solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a canvas, just hide the cursor over the canvas and draw your own sprite on the canvas at mouse position.

Comment: this was a nice and simple solution I didn't think about. will use this approach.

Comment: No problem, best of luck with your development