# Custom Mouse Cursor Javascript Painting Application

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a web application that allows the user to draw on the canvas element. I am using HTML5 and javascript.

I am wondering if it is possible for the mouse to change to a paint brush icon when the user selects to paint and an eraser icon when the user selects to erase etc etc.

Any ideas how I might achieve this? Thanks

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987326/custom-cursor-image-with-javascript

Answer (score 5):

Suppose the only way will be using css cursor property with an url set to your image:

```
body {
   cursor:url('/url/to/required/image.jpg');
}
```

For more details see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/cursor

Or setting it with JS:

```
document.body.style.cursor = "url('/url/to/required/image.jpg')";
```

Comment: But Is that dynamic? Because the cursor depends on the tool the user is using

Comment: By default it is not dynamic. But you can change style using JS. See my updated aswer.